# Почему выводятся неверные данные при парсинге?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, crawling

пишу парсер для сайта, данные которые должны парситься все время обновляются, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что выводит не верные данные, а именно: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI4uy.jpg - должно вывести(снизу вверх), а выводит https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYO5h.jpg. Цвет определяю по классу дочернего элемента. А вывод новых игр по хешу игры. Сделал чтобы выводило 3ю игру.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://rublix.best/")

time.sleep(45)
wheel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/nav/ul[1]/li[2]/a").click()
hash_game = 0
a = 1

'''  Выводит каждую третью игру то есть 0 - грин, 1- ред, 2- грей.
 Выведет грей, на следующей игре ред и тг  '''

while True:
    last_game = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="doubleGame"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div').get_attribute('class')
    color = 0

    named_tuple = time.localtime() # получить struct_time.
    time_string = time.strftime("Время: %H:%M:%S", named_tuple)

    h = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="doubleGame"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/span[1]/p') # путь до хеша последней игры
    if hash_game != h:
        hash_game = h
        if last_game == 'lggr':
            color = 'GREEN'
        elif last_game == 'lgg':
            color = 'GREY'
        elif last_game == 'lgb':
            color = 'BLUE'
        elif last_game == 'lgr':
            color = 'RED'

        t = [str(a), 'game', '{}'.format(color), '{}'.format(time_string)]
        print(t)
        a += 1

        myFile = open('doubleGame.csv', 'a', newline='')
        with myFile:
            writer = csv.writer(myFile, delimiter=';') # Записывает в myFile с разделителем ';' для перехода в след. ячейку.
            writer.writerows([t]) # Записывает список списка переменной t, иначе через каждый символ будет запятая.
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Не совсем ясно, что Вы парсите

Comment: На сайте rublix.best, в разделе Wheel - https://prnt.sc/uff429, паршу данные игр https://prnt.sc/uff4n4, новые игры добавляются на верх

Comment: Очень странно. Но эти данные генерируются прямо на фронте. Они не отправляются на сервер. Вы уверены, что они Вам нужны?

Comment: Могли бы обрисовать задачу?

Comment: Да, нужны, смотрите, скрипт заходит на сайт, в wheel, и выносит атрибут дочернего элемента последней игры(есть в переменной last_game), исходя из значения атрибута выводиться цвет данной игры(в коде есть это, if last game ==...), чтобы из-за цикла тоннами не выводило один и тот же элемент, идет сравнение по hash'у игры(есть в переменной h), если hash разный то в консоль выводиться номер игры, ее значение(цвет последней игры), и время, а также эти данные записываются в .csv файл.

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось очень простым, надо было добавить просто пару слипов, тк данные не успевали полностью обновиться и из за этого и происходила эта путаница.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://rublix.best/")

time.sleep(45)
wheel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/nav/ul[1]/li[2]/a").click()
hash_game = 0
a = 1

'''  Выводит каждую третью игру то есть 0 - грин, 1- ред, 2- грей.
     Выведет грей, на следующей игре ред и тг  '''

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    last_game = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="doubleGame"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div').get_attribute('class')
    color = 0

    named_tuple = time.localtime() # получить struct_time.
    time_string = time.strftime("Время: %H:%M:%S", named_tuple)

    h = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="doubleGame"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/span[1]/p') # путь до хеша последней игры
    if hash_game != h:
        time.sleep(4)
        hash_game = h
        if last_game == 'lggr':
            color = 'GREEN'
        elif last_game == 'lgg':
            color = 'GREY'
        elif last_game == 'lgb':
            color = 'BLUE'
        elif last_game == 'lgr':
            color = 'RED'

        t = [str(a), 'game', '{}'.format(color), '{}'.format(time_string)]
        print(t)
        a += 1

        myFile = open('doubleGame.csv', 'a', newline='')
        with myFile:
            writer = csv.writer(myFile, delimiter=';') # Записывает в myFile с разделителем ';' для перехода в след. ячейку.
            writer.writerows([t]) # Записывает список списка переменной t, иначе через каждый символ будет запятая.
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/517257)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, Во-первых почему не является ответом на вопрос, если я указал решение данной проблемы. Во-вторых я добавил этот ответ, указав, что вопрос решен и проблемы уже нету, а также указал то, как я решил данную проблему.

Comment: Исправлений код добавь и будет ок, а так больше на коммент тянет ;)

Comment: А хорошо) Я просто на форуме недавно и не все знаю, что можно добавлять, а что нельзя.

Comment: Это не форум, а Q&A site ;)

Comment: Да, так будет правильнее)